# total number of lines of a file (counting backwards)

Tags: c, file, eof

For a given file, can I count number of lines backwards? i.e. starting from EOF, counting the lines till the beginning?

I could fseek to the end of the file. Start form there, keep looking for new line char (indication of a new line) and keep incrementing my line_number count. But what should be my ending condition?

Is there any opposite of EOF? :)

My own suggestion: If I am looking for Xth line from end, I could always get it from beginning at this line number : total_lines - X --- fair enough?

Motive: I am interested in getting to Xth line form the end of a HUGE (read really huge) file. So, looking for the most optimal solution.

PS: This is not a homework (though I am a lifetime student :p)

Comment: can I even go backwards from EOF :D ??

Comment: @hari you start from top towards end or reversal but the number of line always remain same ,then why backward ?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do it backwards? If this is homework that's fine, but you should mark it as such.

Comment: @Chris: Appreciate your kind suggestion. Now reason: I want to get to Xth line from the EOF.

Comment: The end condition is an fseek argument of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite of EOF is pos == 0.

The POSIX tail command does this; for example code, see http://www.koders.com/c/fid8DEE98A42C35A1346FA89C328CC3BF94E25CF377.aspx

Answer (score 4):

When I've done this (e.g., wrote a rough equivalent of the standard `tail`) I've read a block from the end, counted the lines in it, if I didn't have enough lines, used `fseek` to go backwards and read another block (but I'm not sure the latter has ever really happened except when I forced it to in testing).

Comment: The OP has a "HUGE (read really huge) file" ... it's pretty much guaranteed that the Xth line won't always be found in the first block read.

Comment: @Jim: the size of the *file* is irrelevant here -- it's the average length of the *lines*, (and the value of X) that matter. The last, say, 10 lines are likely to be in the last 8 kilobytes, regardless of whether they're preceded by 10 megabytes, 10 gigabytes, or even 10 terabytes of other text. When/if it's not, it's because each line is really long, not because of how much text precedes it.

Comment: Of course the size of the file is relevant to whether one will find the requested line in the first block read. If the file is huge, then your block buffer is guaranteed to be smaller than the file, and thus the Xth line may not be found within it. Your logic is bizarre ... of course the 10th line back won't be found in the last N gazillibytes only if the lines are really long, but who said anything about 10? As long as the Xth line occurs in the second half of the file, it's faster to search backwards; for huge files, such X will be huge, or lines will be huge ...

Comment: P.S. It's hard for me to see why this isn't obvious, so it's likely we're somehow talking past each other ... I responded to "I'm not sure the latter has ever really happened" ... if it hasn't, then that implies that the line you were seeking always occurred in the first block read, which implies that you were either always looking for lines near the end, or your files always fit entirely in your block buffer. The latter clearly doesn't apply to huge files, and the former is not a condition stated by the OP ... there's no particular reason to think that the Xth line is within a block of EOF.

Comment: @Jim: I think it implies that his lines were always short, and his `X` was always small. In other words, he wasn't writing a `tail` utility that users would pass arbitrary files and numbers to, he had a specific use case where he needed data near the end of a formatted file. I have occasionally used `tail` itself to get more than a few MB of data, but not frequently. If I spent more time looking at big log files I might, though - search the last million events, or whatever.

Comment: @Steve The OP never said any such thing. I know of plenty of use cases where X is not always small ... not small enough to guarantee that the Xth record will occur in the last block of the file for any block size that can fit in memory. In any case, this issue here is whether the file size is *relevant*, and it clearly is for the reason I pointed out -- the large the file, the more likely it is not to fit within one block. End of this discussion for me.

Comment: @Jim: Of course the OP never said any such thing. Jerry was talking about his own experience, not the OP's. Hence "when I've done this". If the OP's use case differs from Jerry's, he should use a different approach. If it's the same, he could profitably use the same approach. Only the OP knows therefore whether Jerry's solution is good for the OP.

Comment: @Steve "Jerry was talking about his own experience, not the OP's" -- Duh. What I said was that that experience doesn't apply HERE. Goodbye.

Comment: @Steve P.S. This is really really silly. Jerry's "approach" is the approach of tail and the approach that applies to the OP. The issue isn't the "approach", but whether "read another block" will occur in practice. If Jerry's "approach" had been to just quit if the line wasn't found in the first block read, then your comment would make sense. As it is, it's just arguing for arguing's sake.

Comment: @Jim: no. I'm "arguing" because you said "I think we're talking past each other", Jerry didn't respond and hence is presumably getting some work done, and I thought I could see in what way you were talking past each other. You were working on the basis that "ever really happened" means all conceivable uses, Jerry was talking about his own personal uses. And if you say "Goodbye" and then add a PS, you don't get to accuse *me* of arguing for arguing's sake, but you're right, I should have said "see the same thing", not "use the same approach". You don't know whether the experience applies here.

Comment: @Steve Whatever you say, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print lines backwards you can use recursion to do this (not sure what you mean by count because counting the number of lines is the same forwards as it is backwards). This sounds like a homework problem for intro to C so I will refrain from putting code but think of it this way. Read a line, if it's not EOF recursively read the next line otherwise print the line and return.

Comment: You want iteration, not recursion; recursion will overflow your stack (unless writing in a language which optimizes tail recursion, which of course C doesn't).

Comment: Takes quite a bit of lines to do that, he could just place it in a linked list of lines as well while keeping a counter.

Comment: The OP said it was a huge file. Even if that weren't specified, it would be atrocious programming practice (enough for me to fire) to write code *known* to crash just by giving it a large file. And why create a linked list when all that is wanted is the Xth line from the end? In both cases, it helps to actually read the question.

Comment: Well I read the question before it was edited to make it clearer at first I was unsure exactly what he wanted.